# BIOS doesn't detect USB device

Tags: dual-boot, usb, system-installation

I have a problem with installing Ubuntu alongside Windows 8.1 on my Acer Aspire V7.
I've created a bootable USB on Windows (with Universal USB installer), turned off FastBoot and SecureBoot, yet when I press F12 during startup, the USB device isn't an option.

I've tried it with Ubuntu 14.04 and Xubuntu 14.04 but it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

This is an BIOS/UEFI issue.
Make sure `portable device` it the first option, resp. your USB device is the first one in the hard drive boot priority.

Answer (score 0):

Apparent in the Acer Aspire series, you must first change the BIOS (press F2 during boot) to allow booting from USB, then use F12 during boot to choose the USB device.

https://craftedflash.com/info/how-boot-computer-from-usb-flash-drive

http://www.linlap.com/acer_aspire_v7-482pg-9884

Comment: Okay, I changed the boot order. I now have an 'Ubuntu' option. It only gives a GNU Grub command prompt, not the usual 'Try Ubuntu without installing' option.